# Stop a node server in Travis CI

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

So, my code contains unit tests that require a server. So I have sever up and running, my tests pass, but the problem is that I don't know how to stop server, so my build fails because it gets timed out.

Here is my configuration file

```
language: node_js
node_js:
 - "7.10.0"
services:
 - mongodb
env:
 - PORT=6655 IP="localhost" NODE_ENV="test"
script: 
 - npm start &
 - sleep 25
 - npm test
```

Now, how do I stop the node server?

**Edit:** Here are my npm scripts

```
  "scripts": {
    "build-js": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "test": "node node_modules/.bin/mocha ./server/test  --require ./server/test/testHelper.js --watch  --reporter spec --timeout 10000 --compilers js:babel-core/register",
    "start": "npm run build-js && babel-node app.js myApp --presets es2015,stage-2 && nodemon --watch cms/client",
  }
```

Comment: What does `npm start` do?

Comment: @ExplosionPills hey, sorry, I have updated my question

Comment: Since you are back-grounding your `npm start` command, you might have to send a PKILL to the process in order to stop it

Comment: You could use possibly use `pkill node`, but I think you should write your tests to be synchronous in a way that you don't have to start the server to run them

Comment: @ExplosionPills Could you point me to a document that could explain me more on this? The tests are for my apis, the resultant effect that I expect to be caused when the APIs are called. So, I can't understand how would the API calls work, if there isn't a server running.

Comment: The https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest library can probably help you

Comment: So, I tried `pkill node` but what it does is stops the server before all my tests are run. I tried running `pkill node` once in the script step, and once in the after_script step.